# Android: Problema ao buscar último id inserido com SQLiteDataBase (ORM Lite)

Tags: java, android, sql, xml, sqlite

Estou tendo um problema na execução de uma query (com ORMLite) que agrega o retorno a 'ultimaConfiguracao' no qual deve obter o último 'id' inserido na tabela Configuracao.

o método que busca a última configuração é o seguinte:

```
public Integer buscaIdUltimaAtualizacao() throws SQLException {
        GenericRawResults<Integer> raw = this.queryRaw("SELECT MAX (id) FROM configuracao", new RawRowMapper<Integer>() {
            Configuracao c = new Configuracao();
            @Override
            public Integer mapRow(String[] columns, String[] results) throws SQLException {
                if(results[0] != null)
                    return Integer.parseInt(results[0]);
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        });
        return raw.getFirstResult();
    }
```

Classe usando Sqlite:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "configuracao", daoClass = ConfiguracaoDao.class)
public class Configuracao {

    public Configuracao() {
        /*deixar vazio*/
    }

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.DATE, canBeNull = true)
    private Date ultima_atualizacao_artista;

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.DATE, canBeNull = true)
    private Date ultima_atualizacao_diaEvento;

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.DATE, canBeNull = true)
    private Date ultima_atualizacao_evento;
...
```

contexto onde eu realizo as operações:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... paths){
        try {
            this.ultimaConfiguracao = this.confDao.queryForId(confDao.buscaIdUltimaAtualizacao().toString());

            if(ultimaConfiguracao != null){
                //baixa somente o que tem atualização
            }
            else{
                //region MIDIA
                this.query = new ParseQuery("Midia");
                this.query.whereEqualTo("ativo", true);
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List list, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                        if(!list.isEmpty()){
                            for(ParseObject pObject : (List<ParseObject>) list) {
                                publishProgress(((Activity) listener).getString(R.string.m_progress_textView_verificandoAtualizacoes));
                                Midia md = new Midia();
```

Logcat:

```
02-23 22:36:24.097    1446-1453/com.universo91.towersrock W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 313.333ms
02-23 22:36:24.936    1446-1453/com.universo91.towersrock W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 651.381ms
02-23 22:36:25.009    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ java.sql.SQLException: Could not perform raw query for SELECT MAX (id) FROM configuracao
02-23 22:36:25.011    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
02-23 22:36:25.011    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.queryRaw(BaseDaoImpl.java:552)
02-23 22:36:25.011    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ at com.universo91.towersrock.DAO.ConfiguracaoDao.buscaIdUltimaAtualizacao(ConfiguracaoDao.java:78)
02-23 22:36:25.011    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ at com.universo91.towersrock.BL.PSTowersRock.doInBackground(PSTowersRock.java:72)
02-23 22:36:25.011    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ at com.universo91.towersrock.BL.PSTowersRock.doInBackground(PSTowersRock.java:39)
02-23 22:36:25.011    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-23 22:36:25.012    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-23 22:36:25.012    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-23 22:36:25.012    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-23 22:36:25.012    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-23 22:36:25.012    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-23 22:36:25.012    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Getting a writable database from helper DatabaseHelper@28ef97dc failed
02-23 22:36:25.013    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
02-23 22:36:25.013    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidConnectionSource.getReadWriteConnection(AndroidConnectionSource.java:68)
02-23 22:36:25.013    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidConnectionSource.getReadOnlyConnection(AndroidConnectionSource.java:54)
02-23 22:36:25.014    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.queryRaw(StatementExecutor.java:306)
02-23 22:36:25.014    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.queryRaw(BaseDaoImpl.java:550)
02-23 22:36:25.014    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ ... 9 more
02-23 22:36:25.014    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 4 to 1
02-23 22:36:25.015    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.onDowngrade(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:360)
02-23 22:36:25.015    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:254)
02-23 22:36:25.066    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
02-23 22:36:25.066    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidConnectionSource.getReadWriteConnection(AndroidConnectionSource.java:66)
02-23 22:36:25.067    1446-1491/com.universo91.towersrock W/System.err﹕ ... 12 more
```

DatabaseHelper:

```
package com.universo91.towersrock.DAO;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper;
import com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource;
import com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils;
import com.universo91.towersrock.Models.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

    private static final String databaseName = "towersrock.db";
    private static final int databaseVersion = 4;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, databaseName, null, databaseVersion);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, ConnectionSource cs) {
        try {
            TableUtils.createTable(cs, Midia.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(cs, Artista.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(cs, Configuracao.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(cs, DiaEvento.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(cs, Evento.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(cs, Excursao.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(cs, Ingresso.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(cs, Noticia.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(cs, Passageiro.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(cs, PontoDeVenda.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(cs, User.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(cs, Veiculo.class);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, ConnectionSource cs, int i, int i2) {
        try {
            TableUtils.dropTable(cs, Midia.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(cs, Artista.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(cs, Configuracao.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(cs, DiaEvento.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(cs, Evento.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(cs, Excursao.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(cs, Ingresso.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(cs, Noticia.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(cs, Passageiro.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(cs, PontoDeVenda.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(cs, User.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(cs, Veiculo.class, true);
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        super.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pela razão apresentada para o erro: `Can't downgrade database from version 4 to 1`, a versão do banco de dados foi alterado de 4 para 1.

Comment: @ramaral ótimo, porém quando troco para a 4 ou 5 novamente, da o mesmo problema.

Comment: Dá o mesmo erro? Mostre como implementou `SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade`

Comment: @ramaral esta classe é implementada no ORM, não foi eu quem implementou. Teria que olhar na documentação.

Comment: Não dei conta que está a utilizar o *ORMLite*.

Answer (score 1):

Tente ai se isso funciona.

```
long max = this.queryRawValue("SELECT MAX (CAMPO_ID) FROM configuracao");
```

Ou vc pode tentar , adaptar segundo exemplo da documentação
Aqui: 
http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#Raw-Statements

```
// find max id
GenericRawResults<String[]> rawResults =
orderDao.queryRaw("SELECT MAX (CAMPO_ID) FROM configuracao");

// there should be 1 result
List<String[]> results = rawResults.getResults();

// the results array should have 1 value
String[] resultArray = results.get(0);

// this should print the number  
System.out.println("Show Result MAX ID: " + resultArray[0]  );
```

Comment: E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: configuracao.... Acabei de editar a pergunta com a classe helper.

Answer (score 0):

Como diz no logcat, o problema é que não foi criada a tabela configuração, bastou que eu desinstalasse a app e instalasse novamente para que ela acessasse o onCreate() do DataBaseHelper e assim criasse minhas novas tabelas.